# Are abstract members possible in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, properties

I'd like to develop an abstract class to be extended to fit custom requirements. Most of the methods will be fully implemented in this base class. However, it will rely heavily on the values set in the members, which the child class should define. The reason I'm saying "abstract" class is that I want to force the extenders of the class to define values for the members. Is this possible?

I know I can define methods to be abstract and force extenders to implement those. I'm not sure about members. Furthermore, is this good design practice?

Example:

```
abstract class foo_bar
{
    // I want child class to define these
    private $member1 = 0;
    private $member2 = 0;
    private $member3 = 0;

    // Child class and instances can access this
    public function foo()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }

    // Child class must implement this
    abstract function bar();
}
```

Comment: Look at late static binding - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php - though this only applies to methods

Comment: it is good practice, and you can define getters as abstract instead of members. But other than that, what @deceze said.

Comment: For the best practice part you ask about I better leave you a link because this can not be reasonable answered in an answer on SO. Also please read it only to get an introduction into the practice: [Doing it wrong: getters and setters (June 2008; by Greg Jorgensen)](http://typicalprogrammer.com/?p=23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No. There's no such thing as `abstract` properties in PHP.

You may as well just declare those properties as `protected` in the abstract class itself so the child inherits them. Even if you'd declare them `abstract`, there's no guarantee the child implements them *with useful values*, so it has about the same effect.

Comment: Workarounds? Base class has a constructor that accepts a gazillion parameters to set the properties?

Comment: a workaround is to define abstract methods getMember1(), getMember2() etc that you use in your code and any implementation must define.

Comment: @snoopy As I said, just declare them so they're there, you can't make any other guarantees anyway. Maybe forcing the child to implement a bunch of getters would be more of a guarantee, but even there there's no guarantee about the usefulness of the values. Overall, maybe you shouldn't need to force your children to supply so much stuff and restructure your class somehow.

Comment: If your class needs a gazillion properties it is a sign your class is doing too much.

Comment: I'm the one implementing the children classes. So, high degree that the values will be useful. Just thinking about architecture, that's all.

Comment: @PeeHaa - it's just the nature of the library that I am developing. I need a lot of properties atomically defined in order to do the work I need to do.

Comment: Just saying @snoopy76 since this question is tagged OOP. I'm almost certain that if your class indeed has that many properties which need to be set automagically you are violating pSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).